# Opening web pages using search engine

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping, vs-web-site-project

i am trying to open multiple web pages on the same domain. I need those links to scrape some data ( I have permission from the website).
I cannot use the domain name that I actually want to scrape, but as an example:
If a website is
[www.gsmarena.com](http://www.gsmarena.com), and all I want to scrape is all the pages on that website which ends with ends with a particular string:
Example [www.gsmarena.com/*anystring*/*searchstring](http://www.gsmarena.com/*anystring*/*searchstring)*

I hope someone can help me out

Comment: You want those links to be scrapped or the contents on those pages?

Comment: I need the contents. But even if I can get the links that is a win!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you what I would do if I was in your situation, but you will need some experience creating scraping applications (my preferred language for scraping is **C#**.). Here are the steps(needs to be done using scraping application):

- Download main page as a string
- Get links to all categories(or the categories you need)(if you want to use C# then [HTMLAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) will help you to do this)
- Download Category by category and get their product link from there.

I hope it helped you. If you want to know more feel free to ask in comments.